# Send json in FormData

Tags: javascript, json, multipartform-data, form-data

Can I send multilevel javascript object in FormData like in JSON?

For example:

```
{
     items: [
         {'title': 'first', 'amount': 20},
         {'title': 'second', 'amount': 3}
     ]
}
```

In order to send it via FormData I have to do this

```
const data = new FormData;
for(let i = 0; i < obj.items.length; i++) {
    data.append(`items[${i}][title]`, obj.items[i]['titlte']);
    data.append(`items[${i}][title]`, obj.items[i]['titlte']);
}
```

If I do simply

```
data.append(`items[]`, obj.items);
```

Then server sees only '[Object object]'

I can not post JSON, because alongside with these items I send some files.

Answer (score 1):

try to send  `data.append('items[]', JSON.stringify(obj.items));`

Comment: Is there any way to send multiple fields without iterating over all fields?
Like 
data.append('items1[]',JSON.stringify(data.items1));
data.append('items2[]',JSON.stringify(data.items2));

Comment: the other option is to call `.serialize()` on a form. More info [here](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)